# Reading in the same data type to different variables with fscanf

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I'm writing a function to read in a file and assign its various integers into an array of structures for further processing later in the program. However, I'm having trouble assigning the values read to their "correct" array structure -- all the values are simply assigned to `BP.time[position]` by way of variable `time`.

Ideally, my arrays would look like such at the end of the function running:

```
BP.time[position] = {0001, 0002, 0003, 0004}
BP.sys[position] = {500, 400, 300, 200}
BP.dia[position] = {50, 40, 30, 20}
```

Example data file being read in:

```
0001 500 50
0002 400 40
0003 300 30
0004 200 20
```

Example of faulty piece of function code:

Note on code: I know that it is reading in the values from the file, as currently my output looks like such:
`BP.time[position] = {0001, 500, 50, 0002...}` and so on, reading all numbers into only the time variable. When checking other variables, they seem to be outputting (with printf) their address, and not actual numbers from the file.

```
struct bloodPressure // GLOBAL DEFINITION
{
    int time[50];
    int sys[50];
    int dia[50];
}BP; // end struct BP

...

while (fscanf(filePtr, "%d, %d, %d", &time, &sys, &dia) != EOF) // INSIDE A FUNCTION 
    {
        BP.time[position] = time;
        BP.sys[position] = sys;
        BP.dia[position] = dia;
        position++;
        printf("%d\n", time); // DEBUGGING ATTEMPT
        printf("%d\n", sys); // DEBUGGING ATTEMPT
        printf("%d\n", dia); // DEBUGGING ATTEMPT

    } // end while
```

Please also note that I'm a beginner and do not understand things such as the difference between assigning `int` versus `int *`. Thanks for any help with this particular problem.

Comment: Looks like you do it the wrong way. Why not use an array of `struct bloodPressure` with a single (i.e. non-array) members? And if you deal with pointers, `struct` and arrays, you should first learn what they are and how to use them seperately. Don't try to run before you can crouch!

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks so much, that worked perfectly! I didn't know it was supposed to match my input like that, I thought commas were okay/needed/etc. Regarding your second comment, why is it better to use 3 rather than EOF? My understanding is that the EOF will stop reading values when it gets to the end of the file; but, 3 would stop reading values after only reading 3 values in?

Comment: @olaf thanks for your suggestion. Originally, I had it like that. However, I attempted to debug this problem by switching it to what you see now. I've switched it back -- because, as you say, an array of struct bloodPressure makes more sense! It's good that I now know that both can work though! The idea of pointers is somewhat abstract to me...I learned a bit of C++ before C and I wish I hadn't -- it just frustrates me that C++ is more elegant without the pointers of C.

Comment: @user3121023 Oh I get it! Thanks again.

Comment: OT: I had the impression the data structure as shown in your previous question suited better. That is one array of structs. This latter approach bundles the data which longed together under *one* index.

Comment: @alk: That's what I meant with my comment, too. There might be applications this is better, though. For instance if you process the data through a DMA (had this on MSP430 which has a seperate MAC-unit which can be feed by a linear DMA).

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, saw this after having placed my comment. Had upvoted your comment then, but unfortunately ran out of votes for the day ... :}